# MySQL root password setup error

Tags: server, mysql, password

I am working on a project and I have been trying to use MySQL instead of SQLite. So I downloaded MySQL and I am trying to set the root password with `mysql_secure_installation`, but when I submit both passwords, it gives the following error:

```
 ... Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.
```

I have been trying to set the password in mysql by doing:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

and

```
update user set authentication_string=password("password") where user='root';
```

But then it gives syntax errors.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:
One of the problems I have now is that I need the root password to connect to the MySQL server, leaving it empty didn't seem to work

Comment: For many years now there has not been the ability within mysql to set a root user password. mysql now uses your main root password, so one just runs `sudo mysql`

Comment: I just had this happen to me and your question was the top search result after just 10 mins! The error was added only a few days ago in 8.0.29 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_set_password_auth_plugin_error so I think the install script just hasn't caught up. Trying to figure out an easy workaround now...

Comment: I was installing the package from Ubuntu 20.04LTS, and it seems that killing that install script leaves the database accessible by root at least.

Answer (score 55):

I just found the same issue. So, these were my steps:

1. I killed the `mysql_secure_installation` process, `sudo pkill -f mysql_secure_installation`.
2. I logged into `mysql` using:

   ```
    sudo mysql
   ```

   of course, sudo asks my system root password. Once I provided the right root password, I'm connected on mysql as root mysql user.
3. I use my mysql session to run ALTER USER:

   ```
    mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'my-secret-password';
   ```
4. exit

   ```
    mysql> exit
    Bye
   ```
5. Run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command, and complete steps of securing Mysql.

PS.: It seems that neither `/root/.mysql_history` nor `~/.mysql_history` contain my `ALTER USER` command. Anyway, it is good to check out there and remove/edit always you run queries with sensitive information.

Comment: After applying ALTER USER, I can no longer login using `sudo mysql` as it returns this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Is there a way arounf this?

Comment: @FareedFattal after ALTER USER you should to log in mysql using `mysql -u root -p` . This command will ask the password you filled using ALTER USER and once you type it correctly you are logged on the mysql server.

Comment: Its Working Fine For mysql  Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'yournewpassword';
```

Answer (score 1):

Before starting the installation process "sudo mysql_secure_installation":

1. login to mysql and set a root password.
2. exit mysql and run the secure installation
3. login into mysql with mysql -u root -p and the password you set in step 1 and set the following "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;"

A detailed installation guide can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: I am following the guide on DigitalOcean. Step 3 here (auth_socket), allows me to use mysql as root without need to enter password. I still got the error in question, if I run mysql_secure_installation. Rebooting (after password change) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had to re-install MySQL on a headless Ubuntu server running Ubuntu 20.04, and the easiest way round where mysql_secure_installation didn't work when changing the password, I just used 'mysqladmin -u root password' (password is NOT the password to use, but it's the command to change the root password), then it'll ask for a new password, but for some reason the secure installation script messes up, so as long as MySQL root has a password, I'm not really worried about running the secure script, being that I'm not allowing port 3306 through the firewalls and only have local access.